# Adding Values in Overlapping Buffers

Tags: buffer, overlapping-features, summarizing

I have a series of points that represent oil and gas wells (over 1,000), and an emissions value for each well. I created 3 concentric buffers that represent increasing distance from the well, and assigned a fraction of the emission value to each buffer. There are many instances where wells are close together, and their buffers overlap. In these overlapping areas, I would like the emission values of the buffers to add. I tried using the raster to polygon tool, but the overlapping emissions did not sum.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the intersect tool, this will return polygons in your instance, the areas they overlap. You could then do some math for your final values